# Topology given to the tangent space of a manifold at a given point.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I'm learning differential topology from Lee's Introduction to Manifolds and was reading about the tangent space $T_pM$ of a smooth manifold $M$, of dimension say, $n$ at some point $p \in M$. Now, I do understand that $T_pM$ is an $n$ dimensional vector space, but I'm having trouble understanding what does an open set in $T_pM$ look like. I can't visualize what it is. Any help towards that end is appreciated.

Comment: Start thinking about dimensions 1 and 2.

Comment: Why does $T_{p}M need to have a topology? The tangent bundle has a natural topology, but the tangent space at each point is just a vector space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $T_pM$ is finite dimensional, it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$. It is endowed with the standard topology.

**Remark:** Of course the isomorphism $T_pM\cong\mathbb{R}^n$ is not canonical, but any such isomorphism gives the same topology, so it doesn't really matter in this situation.

Comment: Alright. So you're saying that I should try and think of any derivation $v \in T_pM$ as its coordinate vector?

Comment: No! Coordinates are not canonical, you should always try to work without them when it's possible. I'm saying that you have a canonical topology on the tangent space (which behaves well with respect to coordinate choices). Another point of view is that $TM$ is canonically a manifold, and thus a topological space. Now take the subspace topology on $T_pM\subset TM$. (Of course, it will be the same topology I defined above.)